# Help figuring out what this textbook did.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was reading my classical mechanics textbook and this appeared in the chapter for oscillations.

> $$\dfrac{\mathrm d^2x}{\mathrm dt^2}+\omega_0^2x=0\tag{3.31}$$ We can obtain the equation for the phase path, however, by a simpler procedure, because Equation $3.31$ can be replaced by the pair of equations $$\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=\dot x,\quad\dfrac{\mathrm d\dot x}{\mathrm dt}=-\omega_0^2x\tag{3.32}$$

How did the author do that replace the first equation with the second one? (The book is Classical Dynamics by Marion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\dot{x}$ is **Newton's notation** for the derivative of $x(t)$ with respect to $t$, therefore 
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}x+\omega_0^2 x=0 $$
$$ \frac{d^2}{dt^2}x=-\omega_0^2 x $$
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d}{dt}x\right)=-\omega_0^2 x $$
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\dot{x}=-\omega_0^2 x $$
$$ \ddot{x}=-\omega_0^2 x $$

Comment: Oh, never thought you could treat derivative notation like they were fractions.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce $\dot x$ as an abbreviation for $\frac{dx}{dt}$.  That's the first of the two  equations in $3.32$.  Then in  equation $3.31$, the $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$ term is now equal to $\frac{d\dot x}{dt}$, so $3.31$ becomes the second of the two parts of $3.32$.